# R unlist and multiply (date intervals)

Tags: r, dataframe

trying to calculate number of cases between 2 dates, there is table that contains a number and time interval, i want to create output table with dates and sum of cases. The easy (and resolved) problem is:

```
 df <- data.frame(person = c("A", "B", "C"), start = c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-03", "2014-01-04"), stop = c("2014-01-02", "2014-01-06", "2014-01-04") )
 df

 f1 = function() {  #keeping dates
   as.data.frame(table(unlist(apply(df[-1], 1, 
                                    function(x) as.character(seq(as.Date(x[1], "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                                                                 as.Date(x[2], "%Y-%m-%d"), "1 day"))))))}
 f1()
```

and it would return

```
        Var1 Freq
1 2014-01-01    1
2 2014-01-02    1
3 2014-01-03    1
4 2014-01-04    2
5 2014-01-05    1
6 2014-01-06    1
```

what i would need is to summarize the first column instead, with the input data like this

```
 df <- data.frame(cases = c(5, 2, 2), start = c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-03", "2014-01-04"), stop = c("2014-01-02", "2014-01-06", "2014-01-04") )
```

it should return

```
        Var1 cases
1 2014-01-01    5
2 2014-01-02    5
3 2014-01-03    2
4 2014-01-04    4
5 2014-01-05    2
6 2014-01-06    2
```

maybe it would not be even case for unlisting, what can i potentially use to calculate number of cases per day? and is there any way to show 0 values if the date is valid between start and end but does not have any occurrences in the data

EDIT

Aichao's answer is what i needed - the only missing bit is to get 0 sums for example in

```
df <- data.frame(cases = c(5, 2, 2), 
start = c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-04", "2014-01-04"), 
stop = c("2014-01-02", "2014-01-06", "2014-01-04") )
```

to get

```
        Var1 x
1 2014-01-01 5
2 2014-01-02 5
3 2014-01-03 0
4 2014-01-04 4
5 2014-01-05 2
6 2014-01-06 2
```

Comment: `reshape2::melt(DF2,id.vars="cases")`  where DF2 is your second data.frame, is this what you want and shouldn't the value corresponding to `2014-01-04` be 2 instead of 4

Comment: Osssan, no, the value 2014-01-04 corresponds with 2 (the second line of the df) + 2 (the third line of the df), so it should be 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that is in-line with what you are doing with `f1`:

```
f2 <- function(df) {
  df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
    Var1 <- as.character(seq(as.Date(df$start[i],format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                             as.Date(df$stop[i],format="%Y-%m-%d"),"day"))
    cases <- rep(df$cases[i],length(Var1))
    data.frame(Var1,cases)
  }))
  aggregate(df2[,-1], by=list(Var1=df2[,1]), FUN=sum)
}
```

In `f2`:

1. Build a data frame `df2` from the sequence of dates from `df$start` to `df$stop` for each row in `df`. Here, `lapply` is used to loop over each row of `df` and the `cases` for each row is repeated to match the `length` of the resulting sequence of dates. Then use `rbind` to combine each of these data frames by rows.
2. Then `aggregate` (from the `stats` package) this `df2` by dates (i.e., `Var1`) and `sum` up the `cases`.

With your data:

```
f2(df)
##        Var1 x
##1 2014-01-01 5
##2 2014-01-02 5
##3 2014-01-03 2
##4 2014-01-04 4
##5 2014-01-05 2
##6 2014-01-06 2
```

---

One way to fill in the missing dates with `0` as `cases` is to take the aggregated results from the above solution and creating a new sequence of dates spanning the range of dates. This will create the `Var1` column for the new output. Then, it is a matter of copying the cases from the old result to the new output that matches on date:

```
f2 <- function(df) {
  df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
    ## note that we do not convert to characters here because we want to use these later to form the sequence
    Var1 <- seq(as.Date(df$start[i],format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                as.Date(df$stop[i],format="%Y-%m-%d"),"day")
    cases <- rep(df$cases[i],length(Var1))
    data.frame(Var1,cases)
  }))
  df2 <- aggregate(df2[,-1], by=list(Var1=df2[,1]), FUN=sum)
  ## sort previous result by date
  df2 <- df2[order(df2[,1]),]
  ## create new sequence spanning range
  Var1 <- as.character(seq(df2[1,1],df2[nrow(df2),1],"day"))
  ## create cases of zeros matching Var1 in length
  cases <- rep(0,length(Var1))
  ## copy over cases from previous result that matches date
  cases[na.omit(match(as.character(df2[,1]),Var1))] <- df2[,2]
  ## output as data frame
  data.frame(Var1,cases)
}
```

On your updated data:

```
f2(df)
##        Var1 cases
##1 2014-01-01     5
##2 2014-01-02     5
##3 2014-01-03     0
##4 2014-01-04     4
##5 2014-01-05     2
##6 2014-01-06     2
```

Comment: almost perfect, if only you could advise how to get 0 values as well like for

Comment: df <- data.frame(cases = c(5, 2, 2), start = c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-04", "2014-01-04"), stop = c("2014-01-02", "2014-01-06", "2014-01-04") )

Comment: Var1 x
1 2014-01-01 5
2 2014-01-02 5
3 2014-01-03 0
4 2014-01-04 4
5 2014-01-05 2
6 2014-01-06 2

Comment: @Slav: please see my update. This just one way to do it that uses the previous result as the starting point.